# How can I restore /system/bin/toolbox?

Tags: adb, 5.1-lollipop

I accidentally removed `/system/bin/toolbox` on my Android 5.1.1 tablet. Right now I have temporarily replaced it by a `busybox` binary I had at hand, so the system is somewhat usable but not completely functional (e.g. no network connection).

I have tried to pull the `toolbox` binary from other devices I have, but those are either Android 4 or Android 6, so it didn't work due to unresolved linker symbols. Is there a place where I can get a binary for a specific Android version? Or is there a place on my device where a backup is kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the stock ROM (or any ROM, but not preferred) **for your device**. For most brands you'll see a `system/` folder in the ZIP. Now you can take the `toolbox` file and send it to your device. Files taken from ROMs for other devices may work, but there's no guarantee.

If unfortunately you've found a `system.img` file in the ZIP, you should convert it first before attempting to extract any files from it. Tools involved are `simg2img` and `gzip`, which either comes with a Linux system or available from the Linux's default package repo (`apt-get install simg2img` or `yum install simg2img`).